# How to remove version at the end of string with TCL

Tags: tcl

I have file name that ends with different _v01 or _v002

How to remove it with TCL?

I've been trying to use regsub and trimright but can't get right result. I don't understand how to make it work for different types of patterns like
_v1
_v02
_v020

Comment: `how to make it work` ... you didn't mention what your goal is here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regsub`. The key is to have the right expression.

```
% regsub {_v\d+} "file_v01" ""
file

% regsub {_v\d+} "file_v023" ""
file
```

The expression `{_v\d+}` matches literally the string "_v" and follows by one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

The right tool is `regsub`. You just need to use the right pattern (`_v\d+$`).

```
% regsub {_v\d+$} file_v1_v23 ""
file_v1
```

However, you may also need to remove the file extension with `file rootname`. (While it is possible to remove extensions with regular expressions, it is better to use a tool intended for the task as that is tested to handle tricky cases.)